# Retrieving emails from NameCheap Private Email

Tags: python, email

I am using NameCheap to host my domain, and I use their privateemail.com to host my email. I'm looking to create a python program to retrieve specific/all emails from my inbox and to read the HTML from them (html instead of .body because there is a button that has a hyperlink which I need an is only accessible via html). I had a couple questions for everyone.

1. Would the best way to do this be via IMAPlib? If it is, how do I find out the imap server for privateemail.com?
2. I could do this via selenium, but it would be heavy and I would prefer a lighter weight and faster solution. Any ideas on other possible technologies to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just a little bit of testing with telnet will give you the answer to the question 'how do I find the imap server for privateemail.com'.

mail.privateemail.com is their IMAP server.

Comment: Got this from their support online. This is the correct way to do it :) Thanks for the answer.